# Windows Server 2019環境でのDelphi5 アプリの文字入力不具合について

Tags: windows-server, delphi

Delphi5にて作成しているアプリ(以下、アプリといいます。)を、下記Windows Server 2019のリモートデスクトップ環境にて使用しています。

- Windows Server2019 バージョン1809（OSビルド17763.4377）

事象としては、アプリのグリッドビューへローマ字入力を行うと、1文字目で確定される事象が発生しております。IMEの設定変更で回避できるか調整しておりますが、改善に至っていません。
ご質問したい内容につきましては、下記となります。

- Delphi5アプリにて、Windows Server 2019環境で文字入力に適したコーディングはありますか？

併せてアプリの開発環境を下記のとおりお伝えいたします。

- Borland Delphi Professional Version 5.0(Build 5.62)

端的な内容にて恐縮では御座いますが、
ご教示の程宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: Delphi 5 自体がかなり古いバージョンなので、そもそも Windows Server 2019 がサポート対象外な気がします。 https://contec.e-srvc.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2060/~/delphi-5%2C%C2%A0delphi-6-%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9Cos%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1

Comment: 関連の有無は不明ですが、検索するとこんな記事があります。[Board index » delphi » ImeMode - problem with Asian language IME...](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/8b/298801.html) MSで言えば今の時点でVB6を使うようなものでしょうか？ また別の比較的新しい版数と環境でこんな問題があったようです。[Delphi/C++Builder製アプリが日本語変換時にクラッシュ ～Windows 11 バージョン 22H2【21:00追記】](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1447546.html)

Answer (score 0):

以下のことを試してみてはいかがでしょう？(既に試していたならすいません)
IMEを以前のものに置き換える https://www.fmworld.net/cs/azbyclub/qanavi/jsp/qacontents.jsp?PID=8111-2706
互換モードをWindows XP SP3など古いWindowsに設定する https://solution.fielding.co.jp/column/it/itcol04/201906_02/
いまさらDelphi 5もどうなんだという話はありますが、Unicode対応とかDBアクセスとかそれなりにハードルがあるので、簡単にはいかないですよね。